# Build jar file with test classes

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have multiple classes in `main` and a class in `test` package. I use following code in pom.xml and execute `maven install` to create file.

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>test-jar</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

I checked jar file and found, that it contains files from /src/main/ folder, but doesn't contain classes /src/test/ folder, where test class with main method is located.

Comment: Why do you want to have `test` files in a releasable jar?

Comment: By the way you are describing there actually should be a second jar `artifactId-version-tests.jar` containing the test classes.

Comment: Did you check the jar with classifier "tests" or the normal one?

Comment: well if you try `mvn package` you will find the `tests` jar in the `target` folder. (to check the result of mvn install, go to your local `.m2` folder)

Comment: @Prashant : It is a test suite for a webapp.